# Problems running windows services created through python - start doesnt seem to work

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I am creating a windows service through python(code attached below) but it is not working(as per my expectation). My intention is to create a service that will launch a batch file, which will do certain stuffs and when I stop the service then the actions performed by the batch file needs to be stopped.

```
    import win32serviceutil
    import win32service
    import win32event
    import os
    from subprocess import Popen

    class SmallestPythonService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
        _svc_name_ = " MyService"
        _svc_display_name_ = " MyService"
        def __init__(self, args):
            win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
            self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

        def SvcStop(self):
            # Before we do anything, tell the SCM we are starting the stop process.
            self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
            # And set my event.
            win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

        def SvcDoRun(self):
            CWD = os.getcwd()
            p = Popen("pythonTest.bat", cwd=CWD)
            stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
            win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, win32event.INFINITE)

    if __name__=='__main__':
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(SmallestPythonService)
```

First I install the service by navigating to the folder in which the `MyService.py` is available and enter the following: `MyService.py install` and I get the following message:

> Installing service MyService
>
> Service installed

Cross checked in the service management console(`services.msc`) and the services are installed.

Next I start the services by entering the following command: `sc start MyService`.

The services are started but no action is performed. Can someone please help me out in 
understanding if I am missing out on something?

OS: Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter
Python installed : 2.7

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You understand you will see nothing when the bat file is running. Look for cmd in Task Manager to see if working or not.